# Software located on different server as Database

Tags: php, mysql, server

The question I have, is pretty simple, but though I want to know if someone as a better solution.

The problem I have, is putting the MySQL database on a differen Server than the Software itself.
I've heard, that there are security issues when declaring a different host than the "localhost" for the database, so I'm asking If any of you know of an answer or has an idea of how to deal with it.

The Idea behind this task is the following:

If I provide software to a customer, but don't want them to have access to the Source Code (which is pretty simple when the server is in their office), I put it on my own server and give them access to it.
Then the customer says that they don't want us to have access to their data, they store in the database.

So my question now is, how it's possible to have a solution which fits both needs. Mine, and those of the customer.

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have a solution that satisfies both parties with the conditions you have set.

If the software is one you server, then you control it, and you can make it do anything you like. If it has access to their database, then it can do anything you want with that data.

If the software is on their servers then they have access to the source code. Unless you obfuscate it, in which case either:

- They can't (short of not giving it access to the Internet at all) make sure you can't doing something dodgy with their data *or*
- They can deobfuscate it (which is more likely).

There needs to be trust between you and them at some point.

Given most concerns with protecting database have their roots in issues related to compliance to industry regulations, that trust will probably have to come from you.

Write a software license limiting what they can do with the source code. Consider charging them extra for a "Source License".

Comment: Well the company that buys my software doesn't know what that software does in the background. But that's the same with all other software products as well. They have to trust me in that point.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting but not simple question. There are several ways to implement some security mechanism:

- Deploy your php application to customer servers but protected it with something like [ZendGuard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard). In this case your customer can not get simple access for your Source Code and you can not for their data.
- Deploy your application on your site and get access not to full database but to restricted version (restricted for example with using views). In this case your customer has no access to Source Code but you can access for some subset of their data.

Comment: but the software has to have access to read, and write to the database doesn't it?

Comment: yes, but you can read only some subset of data (which is can be configured by database administrator of your customer with using views and procedures). the same concept for writing

Comment: with "you", you mean the software..?
so the software only has access to a subset of data...
but the Software has to have access to all data, because it is the one, who reads and/or writes it to or from the database.

Comment: It all depends on application purposes. For example, do you use third-party application for GoogleDrive? e.g., for creating diagrams. This application needs access only for documents created by its, not the whole GoogleDrive. But another app for syncing files to Dropbox may needs access to entire GoogleDrive. So, the app data permissions depends on app specifity

Comment: hmm.. I understand...
I'll try the idea with ZenGuard.
:) Thank you for your help!